# Intermittent crash on startup with iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios4, crash, uiapplicationdelegate

I have two apps that are in the app store with which a couple of users are having problems. They report that when they load the app it crashes several times but then they can load it. The curious part is that I have never seen this behavior. I have been testing the apps in 3.1.3 while the users have all been using iOS 4.

I suspect that it is a network timeout issue, but I cannot be sure since I cannot see their crash logs. An alternative might be a memory issue since 3.1.3 does not have multitasking while 4 does. Would many apps in background cause a crash (I have seen it slow an iPhone down.)

I wish I could provide some code but since I don't have the crashes I wouldn't know where to start looking. Does anyone have a suggestion as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, why are you not testing on the current OS? Per Apple's guidelines (and good practice) you should be testing and building for the latest released SDK (currently iOS 4.2).

I would download the newest SDk if you haven't already and test your app in the Simulator. If that doesn't simulate the crash, then either upgrade your device to 4.2 or find someone who can test it on their device with 4.x installed.

You can post your applicationDidFinishLaunching method here and we'll see if we can help.

Also, you should be able to download crash reports from iTunes Connect. Hopefully, you archived your distribution build for symbolication.

Comment: Sorry - I was unintentionally vague. I am using the latest sdk (that is 4.2,) and while I am running the production version of the app on an older device (first generation iPod Touch with 3.1.3,) I have tested it on the simulator using 4.2 and on several devices running iOS 4.2 (iPod Touches, older iPhones, and an iPad.) But I do not have access to an iPhone 4 which seems to be the recurring issue with the crashes. I am away from my development machine but I will look at applicationDidFinishLaunching and possibly post it. Thanks -

Comment: Another update. I tested it myself on an iPhone 4 and it works fine. I also tested it on two different iPhone 3gs running 4.2. It crashed on the 3gs but nothing else. So it runs on iPads, an old iPod Touch, and an iPhone 4 but it seems to have problems with the 3rd generation devices (both the iPhone and the iPod Touch.) There are no crash logs on iTunesConnect yet so I can't see them.

Comment: Can you copy/paste your applicationDidFinishLaunching section in your original post?